# Access an array element that is a collection item in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Preface:
Creating a REST API  with Express that will be specifically used to do the CRUD operations on the mongo User collection item below "scheduledReports".
It is an array that would store reporting objects which are created in the front-end.
Each user in the collection as well as any report belong to that user will have a unique ObjectId as an identifier.

Case: User wants to update a report in their collection.

Problem: The PUT request needs to find the user in the collection first then it should find the report that user wants to manipulate. The searches will based on both of their ObjectIds. How to accomplish this in Mongoose?

```
Users Collection
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54c7ed6c4aac70e63c6e8e3d")
  "username" : "test",
  "email" : "test@system.com",

  "scheduledReports" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54ea4d490d24155a73497dc4"),
        "reportURI" : "report",
        "frequency" : "hourly|daily|weekly|monthly",
        "optionalMsg" : "optionalMsg",
        "subject" : "subject",
        "recipient" : "hugurlu@paypal.com",
        "attachments" : [
            "pdf|png|csv"
        ]
    }, 
    ....
```

Simplified Info: Utilizing mongoose, Access to a user in the Users collection using its ObjectID, then access to an element in the "scheduledReports" array again with a given ObjectId. 
Once reached to that element, replace the values (except ObjectId) in it with a new update object.

Comment: Put some more information regarding exactly what you want. Your question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if the second query argument in quotes, and the field that needs to be accessed is given.

```
User.update({username: userId, "scheduledReports._id": ob.report_id},
            {$set{"scheduledReports.$": <new obj> }},function(err,doc){
            //"scheduledReports.$.field" can be used to update that field
           console.log(doc); //if operation is successful doc returns 1, otherwise 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want might be the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).
If `user` is the collection model. Assuming you get the object ids from the front end in `ob`

```
//assuming you get the _id's from the front end in the ob object
//this is more useful when you have simple manipulation on the report
user.update({_id:ob.user_id,scheduledReports:ob.report_id},
             {"scheduledReports.$":<your new obj>},function(err,doc){
    });
//or
user.update({_id:ob.user_id,scheduledReports:ob.report_id},
             {<update operator>:{"scheduledReports.$":<your new obj>}},function(err,doc){
    });
// you can also use "scheduledReports.$.field" to update that field
```

Or another method is

```
user.findOne({_id:ob.user_id, scheduledReports:ob.report_id},function(err,doc){
  if(!err&&doc){
    //doc.scheduledReports will have the array
    //you need to manually search for the particular report id in that array
    // and then manipulate
    //This is more useful when you have complex manipulations.
  }
});
```

Comment: both the user and report ids are being sent from the front end. One thing though would mongose ignore the Object id when updating the array element?

PS: added simplified info.

Comment: am trying the first method, it gives syntax error at this point
    {scheduledReports.$:

so ide marks the colon and says , or ) expected.

Comment: another syntax error on the advanced method as well.

Comment: @hugurlu Edited the methods. Check now